# Google App Engine status code 400

Tags: google-app-engine, status

I have a Servlet running and it is working - but one call is returning StatusCode 400.

I have no idear how to debug this?

Comment: Do you have any exceptions in logs? What kind of operation it is doing? What is that "one" call?

Comment: Nor do we, because you haven't told us anything about your app, or shown us any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get Google App Engine status code 400 try check you header strings:

I found this to be a "\n" in a header string.

/Christian

Answer (score 0):

If you have working requests, you should look at the differences between them and the non-working request.  You should look at the server logs to see if they hold any information or show any thrown exceptions.  You should look at web.xml and make sure that the url you're requesting is mapped to the servlet you want to handle the request.

Comment: Thanks, I found that new line char"\n" in a header string is causing   the error.